# How do I use npm/yarn installs in a .Net Framework WebAPI project?

Tags: css, .net, npm, asp.net-web-api2, yarnpkg

I use scss in my project and want to use bootstrap.scss so I can define a single class inheriting multiple bootstrap classes e.g.

`.myButtonClass { @col-xs-12; @col-sm-6 }`

So I can replace `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"` with `class="myButtonClass"` as I have many buttons that need to be the same. I have installed the yarn extension in VS2017 and can see the Restore Packages (yarn) in my GUI, but yarn is not found in the VS command prompt. So I cannot install the bootstrap scss package.

This is a .Net Framework WebAPI project, not node.js project. There seems to be no examples of how to use js packages in a vanilla .Net Framework WebAPI project.

Or is it simply that I cannot use these style of JS packages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use npm on Windows, this is what you need:

- Download and install [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) (you might need a restart).
- Make sure that node is installed by opening a command prompt and running `node -v` (should print a version number).
- Run `npm -v` and see if it's installed (should be).

Now in the context of an ASP.NET MVC project. The newer versions of Visual Studio (I believe 2017) support `npm` - you can just open the package.json and add dependencies (it will download them behind the scenes).

In case you're using an old version, you can simply open a command prompt, navigate to your project and use npm install from there.

Simply run `npm install bootstrap-scss@4.3.1`

Comment: Does Yarn require npm? I prefer not to install node.

Comment: @Paul `npm` and `Yarn` are two well-known JavaScript package managers. `npm` is `Node.js` Package Manager.
  
  To install packages to and from the public `npm` registry or your company’s `npm` Enterprise registry, 
  you must install `Node.js` and the `npm` command line interface using either a `Node` version manager or a `Node` installer.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I am not being clear. I do NOT want to install Node.js or npm. My question is can I use Yarn and if so how? I can see Yarn options in my VS2017 GUI to Restore, but I cannot find the Yarn command line to actually install the packages in the first place even though I installed the tools.

Comment: I can compile SCSS in my project, but wanted access to Bootstrap.scss, but I cannot install it.

Comment: @Paul, from my knowledge for you to be able to install `bootstrap.scss` by `yarn` or `npm` you going to need `node.js` because `bootstrap.scss` module it's going to be handled as a `node module`.  You just need `node.js` on your development machine. Give a look at this [post](https://nickolasfisher.com/Blog/How-to-Configure-Visual-Studio-to-Implement-the-Yarn-Package-Manager)